# Drop colors from legend which are not in data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to have a function like `scale_color_sex` which assigns predefined colors to the categories of the `color` variable. I have stored these predefined values in a named character vector, which I provide in a modified `scale_color_manual` (see in code).

Ideally, a user of my custom function `scale_color_sex` provides only some data (here `starwars`) and the name of the sex category (here `sex`) and `scale_color_sex` assigns the right color to `geom_point`. The code below produces the desired result.

But: I'd like to drop colors from the legend, which are not represented in the data. In this example it is the "NotInData" category in "red", which I don't want to see in plot. How can I achieve this dynamically?

Bonus points: Can I use some kind of regular expressions on the left-hand side of my color palette / named character?

Any advice, also on other ways to construct a color palette based on the values of `sex` is highly welcome!

```r
library(tidyverse)

scale_color_sex <- function(...){
  scale_color_manual(
    ...,
    values = c(
      female = "#9986A5", 
      hermaphroditic = "#79402E", 
      male = "#CCBA72",
      none = "#0F0D0E", 
      NotInData = "red"
    )
  )
}

starwars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = height, y = birth_year, color = sex)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_sex()
#> Warning: Removed 44 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Comment: Have you modified `starwars`? From what I can see, there at `NA` values but not `NotInData`. Additionally, the rows are still there, so `drop=` (a normal argument in the `scale_*` functions) won't work. Consider filtering out those rows with the `$sex` you don't want to show, and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I want to have a multi purpose function `scale_color_sex` which works for data with `NotInData` category present or not present (the later applies to the `starwars` data, I know there is no `NotInData` category). If there is a `NotInData` category in a other data set, I would like to show it in red, if not, I don't want to see it on the legend. `drop=` is the right way I think, didn't know that option.

Comment: FYI: `drop=` should work as-is without adding it as an explicit argument to your function, it will be passed as part of `...`.

Comment: True, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `drop` argument of `scale_color_manual`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

scale_color_sex <- function(..., drop = FALSE){
  scale_color_manual(
    ...,
    drop = drop,
    limits = force,
    values = c(
      female = "#9986A5", 
      hermaphroditic = "#79402E", 
      male = "#CCBA72",
      none = "#0F0D0E", 
      NotInData = "red"
    )
  )
}

starwars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = height, y = birth_year, color = sex)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_sex()
#> Warning: Removed 45 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want! I had a look into it, but it seems I am running into an open issue in the latest ggplot version https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4534

Answer (score 0):

Just because you cannot see red dots does not mean they should be dropped.

Minor point: in my version of `starwars`, I have no `NotInData`, but I do have `NA`. I'll reassign those for this discussion.

```r
starwars$sex[is.na(starwars$sex)] <- "NotInData"
```

First, most of the rows with `"NotInData"` in sex have no height/birth_year to plot:

```r
library(dplyr)
filter(starwars, sex == "NotInData")
# # A tibble: 4 x 14
#   name           height  mass hair_color skin_color eye_color birth_year sex       gender homeworld species films     vehicles  starships
#   <chr>           <int> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr>     <chr>  <chr>     <chr>   <list>    <list>    <list>   
# 1 Ric Olié          183    NA brown      fair       blue              NA NotInData <NA>   Naboo     <NA>    <chr [1]> <chr [0]> <chr [1]>
# 2 Quarsh Panaka     183    NA black      dark       brown             62 NotInData <NA>   Naboo     <NA>    <chr [1]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
# 3 Sly Moore         178    48 none       pale       white             NA NotInData <NA>   Umbara    <NA>    <chr [2]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
# 4 Captain Phasma     NA    NA unknown    unknown    unknown           NA NotInData <NA>   <NA>      <NA>    <chr [1]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
```

There is one, let's look at it more closely:

```r
filter(starwars, between(height, 180, 190), between(birth_year, 60, 70))
# # A tibble: 3 x 14
#   name           height  mass hair_color   skin_color eye_color birth_year sex       gender    homeworld    species films     vehicles  starships
#   <chr>           <int> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>        <chr>   <list>    <list>    <list>   
# 1 Wilhuff Tarkin    180    NA auburn, grey fair       blue              64 male      masculine Eriadu       Human   <chr [2]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
# 2 Quarsh Panaka     183    NA black        dark       brown             62 NotInData <NA>      Naboo        <NA>    <chr [1]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
# 3 Jango Fett        183    79 black        tan        brown             66 male      masculine Concord Dawn Human   <chr [1]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
```

The middle row is fairly close in the other two values, so it is likely being masked in your plot. Let's plot *that* data.

```r
filter(starwars, between(height, 150, 200), between(birth_year, 50, 100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = height, y = birth_year, color = sex)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_sex()
```

[image: ggplot with red dot showing]

showing the red `"NotInData"` dot in the middle. (If you were to plot the whole data on a larger scale/resolution, you might see it break out.)

If you don't want to plot them, however, best method is to filter it out before sending to `ggplot`, and by default it will be removed from the legend.

```r
filter(starwars, sex != "NotInData") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = height, y = birth_year, color = sex)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_sex()
```

[image: ggplot with "NotInData" removed from legend]